# django app with a generic name

Tags: django

Django tutorials everywhere use constant-set application name all around - in urls file, in HTML templates, in views. But if I want to distribute an application and let the user sets it name (i.e. its URL postfix on `http://server.com/appname`) - how can I do?

I must have some common name setting then in configuration, but how to work it for template files, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that matters with reference to the URL is the app's urlconf. As long as you do your imports via the app's package, e.g. `appname.models`, `appname.views`, etc., all consumers of your app will have to do after installation is add it to their `INSTALLED_APPS` and `include()` it in their urlconf. Everything else will be found by Django provided they are in their default locations.

Comment: and what about url matching in urls.py, which starts with app name?

Comment: Entries in the app's urls.py should not need to start with the app name. Where the app is rooted should be determined by the project, not the app.